# How to correctly create a java keystore file from PEM files provided by a Certificate Authority?

Tags: java, tomcat, jetty, ssl-certificate, keystore

I'm trying to get a secure site running over SSL with Jetty. I've received 4 PEM files from a Certificate Authority:

- 1 Root Certificate
- 2 Intermediate Certificates
- 1 Certificate for my site

But I can't get it working. Either the site rejects requests completely or it works but doesn't recognize the certificate and the browser gives a warning. I've tried the following:

```
keytool -keystore keystore.jks -import -alias server -file server.crt -trustcacerts
```

...but this results in requests to the site being rejected immediately with Chrome saying the webpage is unavailable - no errors on the server at all. I've also tried this:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out keystore.pkcs12 -in server.crt -inkey server-private-key.pem 
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.pkcs12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype jks
```

...and this results in the site responding to requests but still warning about the certificate not being trusted.

What do I need to do (if anything) with the root certificate and intermediate certificates. Are my attempts failing because I'm not using them? I can't find any information that pieces together what I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine all the certificates together. Your server.crt will look like this

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>   1 Certificate for my site
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>   1st Intermediate Certificate
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>   2nd Intermediate Certificate
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>   1 Root Certificate
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----

Use commands:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -clcerts -in  server.crt -inkey server-private-key.pem -out keystore.pkcs12

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.pkcs12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype jks
```

Comment: Does the order of the intermediate certificates matter and if it does, how would I know which should come first?

Comment: Regardless of the answer to that last question, it works - thanks buddy!

Comment: @RTF I don't know the precise answer to this question, but many sources say that you should put certs from "leaf" to root.